# Wcf transport security

Tags: wcf

I was trying to understand the difference between Transport security and message security from the below link and came across the following content.

The http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648863.aspx says that

**When using transport security, the user credentials and claims are passed by using the transport layer. In other words, user credentials are transport-dependent, which allows fewer authentication options compared to message security.**

Can someone please explain me the meaning of above statement with an example if possible ?

It has mainly two parts which I could not understand :

1. user credentials are transport-dependent.
2. allows fewer authentication options compared to message security.

Comment: The answer to "what is different between them" is written in the manual. It would really help if you'd tell what you are trying top accomplish, so we don't have to explain all of the security settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read further in those article, you yourself might be able to make out.

If you see TCP/IP or OSI Layers of the Protocol suit you will notice that upto Transport layer communication is mostly dependent on communication mechanism. The protocols of Transport layer are limited (HTTP, TCP, IPC, MSMQ) for transporting of data. They transport all the data in same manner irrespective of the type of data. Here the channel that is transporting is made secure.

On the other hand in message level security, it is message that is secure. You can use any type of mechanism to encrypt / authenticate your message, and in this case Transport level security provides added advantage.

In simple term, A, B and C are three persons. A wants to send a message to C and B is transporter of the message. If A send his message in a simple envelop, then the message is as secure as the transporter that is B. But if A send a message locked in a box and only C has its key, then his message is secure as B plus it has security of the locked box.

Hope this helps.

Further going with the above analogy, if the transporter B is say your postal service, then A has limited options of having security and limited flexibilty to change B's security provision as those are decided by another party (the Postal Department). But in case you are sending a locked box, the locking mechanism is your choice, you have flexibility to choose type of lock of your own choice as long as C agrees and can open it.

Comment: I liked the A,B,C analogy and i am getting closer to the understanding. But could you also please elaborate on my second point please ?